# jQuery stop(true, true) to jump to end of all animations in queue

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, queue

I have been using jQuery's `stop(true, true)` method to clear running animations so the next one starts immediately. I noticed that the first parameter, `clearQueue`, clears the entire animation queue but the second parameter, `jumpToEnd`, only jumps to the end of the currently running animation and not the ones that were removed from the queue. Is there a way to have it clear and jump to the end of all queued animations?

I've ended up chaining a few `stop(false, true)` calls instead, but this will only handle 3 queued animations, for example.

```js
$(this)
  .stop(false, true)
  .stop(false, true)
  .stop(false, true)
  .addClass('hover', 200);
```

**Edit:**

I ended up adding my own method, `stopAll`, as per Ates Goral's answer:

```js
$.fn.extend({ stopAll: function () {
    while (this.queue().length > 0)
      this.stop(false, true);
    return this;
  } });
```

```js
$(this).stopAll().addClass('hover', 200);
```

I hope someone else finds this useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery 1.9 introduced the [.finish()](http://api.jquery.com/finish/) method, which achieves exactly that.

Answer (score 6):

Chaining multiple `stop(false, true)` makes sense. Instead of hard-coding a fixed number of chained calls, you could check the queue length:

```
while ($(this).queue().length) {
    $(this).stop(false, true);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AB33X/

Answer (score 0):

I also notice from the documentation of the .finish() method in jQuery 1.9 that

```
Animations may be stopped globally by setting the property $.fx.off 
to true. When this is done, all animation methods will immediately 
set elements to their final state when called, rather than displaying an effect.
```

There is also a nice demo of the various methods on the [.finish()](http://api.jquery.com/finish/) documentation page.

Answer (score 0):

Test for presence of class (set upon hover and removed on mouseOut animate callback) before staring new animation. When new animation does start, dequeue.

```
$("div").hover(function(){
    if (!$(this).hasClass('animated')) {
        $(this).dequeue().stop().animate({ width: "200px" });
    }
}, function() {
    $(this).addClass('animated').animate({ width: "100px" }, "normal", "linear", function() {
        $(this).removeClass('animated').dequeue();
    });
});
```